# Creating a full text search page for a table

Tags: node.js, search, express, mongoose, full-text-search

Hi i am creating a search option for a mongoose collection. The problem is with keywords handling. I need to handle keywords such as if they are in "" they should be treated as single word, and if they are comma separated or space separated then they should be treated as OR conditions parameter like these how can i track multiple inputs in "" and comma separated. Any reference or example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [$text](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) operator documentation.

Let's assume you have a collection called `posts` that has the following documents:

```
{postText: 'The dog ran really fast.'},
{postText: 'The cat ran pretty slow.'},
{postText: 'That hampster is crazy fast.'}
```

Make sure you have created a text index.

```
db.posts.createIndex({postText: "text"})
```

For your -OR- case, just pass in the keywords separated with a space.

```
// this will return all documents
db.posts.find({$text: {$search: 'dog cat hampster'}})

// this will return two documents (dog & hampster)
db.posts.find({$text: {$search: 'really fast'}})
```

To match a phrase exactly, enclose it in quotation marks.

```
// this will return one document (dog)
db.posts.find({$text: {$search: '"really fast"'}})
```

You can combine them too.

```
// this will return all documents
db.posts.find({$text: {$search: '"really fast" cat'}})
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks @derek soike for your suggestion. But when input is provided from user how can i categorize whether it is a single word like "really fast" or 2 words "really", "fast"??